# ldap modify add identical values to multivalue attributes

Tags: php, ldap

I need to add some identical values, but `ldap_modify` errors with `Type or value exists`.
How to manage this?

I tried so far:

- read about `ldap_modify` on `php.net`

Task: I have attribute `FIELD` and attribute `FIELD_TYPE`.
Every field could have any type, so `FIELD_TYPE` becomes not unique.
If there is another way to set information about field types?

Comment: That doesn't make sense.  Even if it worked, how would you associate a given field_type attribute with a given field attribute?  There's no ordering.

Comment: see [type or value exists](https://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/07/28/type-or-value-exists/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why? This is a violation of the LDAP protocol, and it serves no purpose that I can see.

Comment: Well, thank you. I will use tree structure with one more level.